# Lavender turning brown

Tags: flowers

[image]

[image]AFEO7.jpg

I've looked at the roots and they seemed to be ok, whiteish.

has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a Lace Lavender (Lavandula pinnata - [see a photo here](https://www.anniesannuals.com/plants/view/?id=4545)) from the Canary Islands. Seems like a mature plant for the size of pot it is in and has probably exhausted resources. Looks like there are some prime shoots at the top available for cuttings to make new plants and give it a reboot.

Comment: thank you ,i will try!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what that plant is (though it is vaguely familiar) except to say it's  not Lavender; whatever, the main problem is the too small pot it's in. Find a larger pot with drainage holes and put it in that, using new potting soil. Don't stand it inside that black outer pot you're currently using, because when you water, it likely runs straight through to the bottom, leaving the plant short. Use a tray if you really  need something to catch excess water and empty it out 30 minutes after watering if there is still water inside it.

In regard to the plant, have you ever seen it flower? Are the leaves slightly furry, velvety to touch, or completely hairless and smooth?

UPDATE: Lavandula pinnata, well that's a new one on me. Its only half hardy, so depending what the winters are like where you are, its probably not a good idea to cut it back now to get rid of the dead. It still needs a bigger pot though, and a different pot to stand inside...

Comment: yeah, i have seen it bloom, Colin shared a picture of how it looks.

Comment: Thanks... not one I know, but then I live in the UK, and its only half hardy here. I've updated my answer, because the requirement for a new pot doesn't change...